# Why can users mark their own question as a favorite?

Tags: discussion

My understanding of a favorite question is that it is supposed to be make accessing it later easier for you (if this is wrong - please tell me.  I get this idea from my use of favorites for a lack of information about what favorites actually are in the help section).  If this is the case, then why should users be able to mark their own questions as favorites, as they can just go into 'questions' in their own profile?

Comment: I posted  485 Questions to date. If I wanted to remember a specific one of these, going into "Questions" on my profile wouldn't be of much help. #hi-rep-users-problems

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "favourite" feature has no particular purpose, its application is unrestrained so we can use the feature whoever is best for us. I know one guy who uses it to mark his own questions which he wants to put bounties on once the two-day grace period expires.

Comment: I do it when I get particularly good answers I want to read properly later on when less busy.